# Mesh can`t partially be edited after joining objects

Tags: edit-mode, weight-painting

So I have this Model I made and I joined a few parts with shared materials together, and now I simply can not edit the faces / verts / edges on the joined parts at all anymore.
The weird thing is, if I unhide everything, the verts show up again and can be manipulated, but that only lasts until I swap out to object or any other mode and then they are "hidden" again.
The frustrating part here is that I can not weightpaint at all, since I can not select anything after leaving edit mode - only the verts and faces of the other half of those joined objects can be used as it would be expected...
I tried a bunch of things, like checking if shapekeys have anything to do with this, I tried copying or duplicating the faces, or the entire object - the result is always the very same face-groups not working properly... did I "lock" them somehow? I'm completely lost here...
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it's a bug, as you've seen it can be fixed by pressing Alt H, maybe use another Blender version, or reimport the object?

Comment: tried that too... literally anything i do with the existing object - like duplicating, reimporting, disecting and rejoining - nothing seems to change this weird effect.
if i copy the faces, then the new copies ahve the same weird properties, too.
but Alt H doesnt work outside of Edit Mode - so I still can not weight paint those areas, even if I select them before switching modes, they will be unselected automatically...

Comment: The problem was noticed but I thought it was fixed in the latest versions

Comment: well... xD
was there a known fix or workaround?

Comment: could you please share your object (at least a part of it)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: ya sure...  how exactly do i even do that? xD

Comment: upload the file, and copy paste the URL it will give you

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17eOju35H1ZDnzhw-Z0_WFO_-YgoNu0kz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: everything works fine here, have you tried with the latest Blender version? Or exporting as an .fbx and reimporting, etc?

Comment: yes i just isntalled the latest version and now it works - i really had 2.90 and wasnt aware of it <.<
i feel like an idiot ...
thank you for your time >.<

Comment: no problem, you couldn't guess that it was a bug  ;)